# How to replace fragments using Navigation from Jetpack?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm setting up the navigation for child game and I have some problem with backstack navigation.
So app contains  Splash Screen, 4 pages (fragments) to collecting some Cards with game info and Main Fragment.
So app flow: Splash ->First-> Second -> etc
UseCase: User finished First Step and started Second, click on BackButton and should redirect to the MainFragment with data instead the First step .

I'm using the Navigation from Jetpack and Forward navigation is perfect. But how can I do custom back navigation?
In UseCase back Stack contains: Splash -> First -> Second
But when User clicks on backButton back stack should behaves like
App finished <- MainFragment <- Second Step

To remove Splash screen from backstack I use in the nav_graph.xml

```xml
    app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

To insert MainFragment before Second Fragment I make navigation like this

First ->(navigate with inclusive popUp) -> Main -> Second

If MainFragment is tiny ( do not contains many logic to display some data) it works perfectly, I didn't see MainFragment when navigate from 1st to 2nd.
But when my MainFragment contains more logic, then User can see this fragment about 1 second.

**How to insert Main Fragment to the back stack silently?**

Comment: You can take a reference from this repo i have used the Navigation from Jetpack and its working perfectly fine.
https://github.com/yash786agg/Dagger2Kotlin

Comment: @yash786 thanks... but it doesn't fit to my question

Comment: Can you show us your navigation graph?